# Unable to connect to LocalDB

Tags: sql, localdb

I'm trying to connect to LocalDB in Visual Studio 2015. I have LocalDB installed, but when I attempt to connect to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` it states that it isn't even there. Can anyone assist? I can't even find it in SSMS 2014.

[image]

#### Update:

Error message that I receive:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Visual Studio Community 2015.

- Tools > Connect to Database

[image: connect to database]

- Choose Microsoft SQL Server
- Data Provider will be .NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server
- Continue

[image: choose data source]

- Server name should be (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB
- Click on Test Connection. You should receive Test connection succeeded.

[image: type in server name]

That should do it for you.

[image: see local db in action]

Comment: That's just the issue, the server isn't there.

Comment: Can you elaborate as to what you mean by server isn't there?

Comment: Also note that, in your question, you use `LocalDB\MSSQLocalDB`. It should be `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`. Notice the 2 `L`s in MSSQLLocalDB.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have updated my original post to show the error I get.

Comment: Let me take a look at this in a minute

Comment: Can you close Visual Studio, open it again and try your connection again?

Comment: When I took that screenshot it was a fresh instance of VS

Comment: Close Visual Studio. Go to Start > Run > cmd.exe > type `sqllocaldb create "v12.0"`. Open Visual Studio and try your connection again. What happens now? If it doesn't work, change the server name to `(localdb)\v12.0` and try test connection again. What do you see next?

Comment: That worked. Now I just need to figure how to get a lightswitch program to connect to that and stop erroring out. I can connect to the (localdb)\v12.0 but not MSSQLLocalDB