# ASP MVC Project Not Able To Connect to LocalDB

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, localdb

I did a re-installation of Windows 10 and hence Visual Studio 2015. After that my ASP MVC project is not able to connect to LocalDB database anymore. I get the following error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

The current Visual Studio installation runs with SQL Server 2016 LocalDB, and I believe the previous (downloaded August 2015) was running with the 2014 version.

The following is a screenshot of where I tried to access the database...

[screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Xj0b.png)

I also realize there are instances when the system is able to read from the database and other instances where it is not.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your ASP code where you are connecting to the database.

Comment: Hello Sean, I've added a screen shot to the question. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to connect to LocalDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34303211/unable-to-connect-to-localdb)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The web app is able to connect when the application starts and does a few reads from the database. But after that it's not able to access the database anymore.

Comment: Can you verify that the SQL Service is running?  I've had to start that manually a few times after a Windows 10 install in the past...

Comment: Yes... it's running.